# TweenLite does not animate

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I am trying to do a simple animation of top-margin using GreenSocks TweenLite for Javascript. I've used the library many times but, for some reason, it's not working this time. Note: The "onComplete" is firing but, no matter what element I use, I cannot animate any CSS properties on HTML elements.

HTML

```
<div id="GS_PipelineHeadline h2"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
TweenLite.to("#GS_PipelineHeadline h2", 0.5, 
{ 
    "margin-top": 0, 
    ease: "Back.easeOut", 
    onComplete: function () 
    { 
        console.log("Crap"); 
    } 
});
```

Here is a real quick JSFiddle I created that includes all the CSS, JS and HTML.
http://jsfiddle.net/mBPug/

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it!

Comment: It might help if you made a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Good call. I just updated my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- add the [CSS plugin](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js) to your fiddle
- `"margin-top"` wasn't going to do much, use `top` instead

.

```
TweenLite.to("#GS_PipelineHeadline", 0.5, {
    top: 0,
    ease: Back.easeOut,
    onComplete: function () {
        console.log("Crap");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBPug/4/

Comment: No, this doesn't get the effect I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is reveal the h2 and h3. I tweaked a few things in the JS fiddle to show what I'm trying to accomplish. If I use JQuery animate, it works. If the only issue was the CSS plugin, I might be able to get it to work now. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Since my answer is based on your original question I believe this is solved. However if you're still having problems with the animation itself you should open another question.

Comment: Hey Tim- It looks like it was just the CSS plugin. I've never included that before and I haven't had a problem. I'm creating something for a legacy site so I was trying to keep the number of plugins and new JS files to a minimum. But, when I added it to the site, it popped up started working immediately. Thanks for your help.