# Using greensock with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs, gsap

I'm not able to get TweeLite to work with browserify. I'm an extreme noob when it comes to CommonJS.

I've installed gasp v1.13.2 using Bower and include it like this:

```
var TweenLite = require("../../bower_components/gsap/src/minified/TweenLite.min.js");
```

I don't get any errors when using it, but my animations don't work. According to gsap docs this version should work without a shim. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone provide a working example?

https://greensock.com/gsap-1-13-1

I've just started on a project so I dont have any interesting code to show. I'm using the [gulp-starter](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter) boilerplate.

Comment: Make sure you also include the cssHook, as far as I can remember this is used to animate by CSS3 transitions or javascript animation, depending on browser support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411730/tweenlite-does-not-animate

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue. When I include the same src file in the document body and refer to window.TweenLite my animations work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I don't know how to do that as the browserify code doesn't work without a server to interpolate it right?

Comment: Upvote for the username!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the uncompressed GSAP libraries. I'm successfully using them through `browserify` and installed with `bower`. Like this:

```
var TweenLite = require('../bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js');
var TimelineLite = require('../bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js');
var CSSPlugin = require('../bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/CSSPlugin.js');
```

However, if I switch to the compressed builds `browserify` no longer finds the modules.

It appear like the compression methods used to generate the minified builds somehow broke the module exports.

Comment: Yes, it does. But you can easily minify it with the rest of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

GSAP is also available through NPM so you should be able to install it via:

```
npm install gsap --save
```

and use it the same way other libraries are referenced in the gulp-starter project eg in  view.coffee:

```
_          = require 'underscore'
Backbone   = require 'backbone'
Backbone.$ = require 'jquery'
plugin     = require 'plugin'
//this line below makes TweenLite available in the browser in my quick tests.
gsap       = require 'gsap'
```

Comment: This works, but it means that I'm including all four libraries and all the other add-ons instead of just TweenLite. It adds ~900kb to my code which is unacceptable.

Comment: That's not true. `require('gsap')` is the same as including `TweenMax.js` **only**