# Install tweenmax using bower

Tags: bower, gsap

Is there a way to install tweenmax using bower?

I've been looking into angular animations and I noticed the egghead tutorial uses tweenmax but it imports it directly into the html. I want to use bower to import so that I can have my imported packages all managed take advantage of the gulp build process to create the minified vendor script.

Comment: these may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325273/using-greensock-with-browserify & http://greensock.com/forums/topic/11078-small-issue-browserify-gsap-minified/

Comment: Hi Tahir, thanks for the links. They're great but I don't think they help me further with finding a bower link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that they name tweenmax as GSAP. Correct me if I'm mistaken but I believe this is the same thing esp looking at the main section of the bower file ([git repo](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS)) which points to tweenmax. Thus, I installed using:

```
bower install gsap --save
```